# Uncorrectable Machine Check Exception on HP DL360 G7

Tags: hardware, hp, hp-proliant, central-processing-unit

i have about every hour in IML (hplog) from HP DL360 G7 record:

---

```
CRITICAL: CPU - Uncorrectable Machine Check Exception (Board 0, Processor 1, APIC ID 0x00000003, Bank 0x00000005, Status 0xBE000000'00800400, Address 0x00003FFF'811239E0, Misc 0x00000000'00007FFF)
```

---

```
hpasmcli> show server
System        : ProLiant DL360 G7   
ROM version   : P68 09/30/2010
iLo present   : Yes
```

Can someone tell me what part is being referenced by the IML status codes above?

Thank in advance!

Comment: This is referencing your CPU and its related memory bank.

Comment: Was this ever resolved?

Answer (score 2):

Please upgrade the BIOS on the server to the current revision. If this is reproducible on such a regular interval, that is absolutely the first thing I would try.

The safest way to run this update is to use the offline [HP Service Pack for ProLiant DVD](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/server-software/product-detail.html?oid=5104018#!tab=features) image. If not, can you tell us what operating system is in use? You can download specific updates for your server [from here](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/public/psi/swdHome/?cc=us&cc=us&lang=en&lang=en&sp4ts.oid=4091409&ac.admitted=1395316627843.876444892.199480143).

Beyond that, this could be a system board issue. You can try moving/reseating the DIMMs to see if the error message changes (following the DIMM). If it doesn't, it's likely the CPU socket for Processor 1. Inspect the LGA socket for bent pins.

You can also call HP ProLiant Support...

Comment: If you choose to call HP support, make sure to have an [HPS report](http://update.external.hp.com/HPS/HPSreports/) result readily available. They will ask you for it in any case.

Comment: @syneticon-dj Not really. I've never been asked for that.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/ProLiant-Servers-ML-DL-SL/DL380G7-Uncorrectable-Machine-Check-Exception/td-p/4766324) for more people experiencing a similar problem.

Possible workaround: In the BIOS, change the Power Regulator mode to "Static High Performance"

Resolution is likely brought by the May 5, 2011 BIOS update:

> Resolved an issue that may result in any of the following conditions:
>   operating system stops responding, unexpected system reset, Blue
>   Screen when using a Microsoft Windows operating system, kernel panic
>   when using a Linux operating system, or Purple Screen when using
>   VMware ESX. A message may be displayed by the operating system or
>   logged in the HP Integrated Management Log (IML) when this issue
>   occurs indicating an "Uncorrectable Machine Check Exception." However,
>   there are instances where the system resets before the operating
>   system displays an error message and instances where the IML contains
>   no log entry when this issue occurs. This issue does not occur if the
>   Minimum Processor Idle State is configured for No C-states or
>   C1E-state.